# Equivalence of various notions of injectivity for partial functions

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations, partial-functions

Let $A$ and $B$ denote sets.

> **Definition.** Given a partial map $f : A \rightarrow B$, let us define that a *partial inverse* of $f$ is any partial map $g : B \rightarrow A$ satisfying $$fg \leq \mathrm{id}_A, \qquad gf \leq \mathrm{id}_B,$$
>
> *Notation.* Expressions of the form $p \leq q$ mean that for all $a \in A$, if $p(a)$ is denoting, then so too is $q(a)$, and $p(a) = q(a)$.

I have a sneaking suspicion that the following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is injective
2. $f$ has a maximal partial inverse
3. $f$ has a partial inverse $g$ satisfying $fgf = f$ and  $gfg = g.$

I'm pretty confident about the equivalence between $1$ and $2$. Let's collectively call these two condition $(*)$ since they're equivalent.

Also I can prove that $(*)$ implies $3$, but the converse is non-obvious (to me, at least).

> **Question.** Does 3 implies $(*)$?
>
> If so, I request a proof.

Comment: Why not handle a partial function by restricting it domain to where it functions?

Comment: @WilliamElliot, that's a good way to handle them, but how does that imply that from (3) we can deduce (1) and (2)? I don't think the proof can be avoided simply through redefinition.

Comment: What good are partial functions,, those things with a partial subset for a domain?

Comment: @WilliamElliot, well, they arise quite naturally in analysis. For example, $x \mapsto 1/x$ is merely a partial function $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R},$ not a total function. They also arise quite naturally in computer science; definitions by recursion often produce mere partial functions.

Comment: I don't understand that you say points (1) and (2) are equivalent. For instance, take $f$ to be the only total function from $\{1,2\}$ to $\{0\}$. It is not injective, but there is only one partial inverse, which is then maximal...

Comment: Hmm you're right. I think that if the Id_A condition is removed that should fix the problem. Thoughts?

Comment: @Ideophage in fact I think every pf should have a maximal partial inverse under the new definition. Maybe what I had in mind was "maximum" partial inverse. Sigh. This question needs a major rewrite